# How to click on the radio button through the element ID attribute using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a radio button and input element, it has an `id` of group and value of `In_Group`. There are 4 different radio buttons with the same id but different values hence I am trying to select the correct one i am looking for.

```
<input class="custom-radio" id="group" name="group" type="radio" value="In_Group">
```

I tried something like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id='group' and @value='In_Group')]"))
```

But the element is not found could someone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#group[value='In_Group']"));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='group' and @value='In_Group']"));
  ```

---

However, as it is a `<input>` element and possibly you will interact with it ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.custom-radio#group[value='In_Group'][name='group']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='group' and @value='In_Group'][@class='custom-radio' and @name='group']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: Hey, `//input[@id='group' and @value='In_Group']` is what i was looking for Thanks a lot