# error: 'Element should have been select but is a ng-select' clicking on a ng-select dropdown option using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Using selenium c# - I am unable to click on a value of an angular dropdown list.

**code:**

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("Status"))).SelectByIndex(2)
```

> error: 'Element should have been select but is a ng-select'.

I also tried clicking on the dropdown first then targeting the values after dropdown list shows. I got '`Element should have been select but is a div'`

Any Ideas on the latest way to use **selenium c#** for selecting values of ng select, ng options select dropdowns, would be appreciated.

[image: HTML page]

Comment: You can not use select class for sure. Can you show us the code that you've tried for this `I also tried clicking on the dropdown first then targeting the values after dropdown list shows`

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.Name("Status")).Click();
            

new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("Status"))).SelectByText("Rejected");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Element should have been select but is a ng-select
```

...implies that the element is a [angular-ngselect](/questions/tagged/angular-ngselect) element so you can't use the *Select* Class.

---

As the desired element is an angular-ngselect element so to `Click()` on the second option from the angular dropdown list you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("ng-dropdown-panel[aria-label='Options list']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("ng-dropdown-panel[aria-label='Options list'] div.ng-option.ng-star-inserted[id$='2']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//ng-dropdown-panel[@aria-label='Options list']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//ng-dropdown-panel[@aria-label='Options list']//div[contains(@class, 'ng-option ng-star-inserted') and contains(@id, '2')]"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click on drop down bar like this :

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Status")).Click();
```

and after that you should see all the **options**. Now I see you are still using `select` class to `select` the `option`, which will not work out since HTML is not built up using `Select` and `options` tag.

Now try to click directly :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("xpath of the option should go here")).Click();
```

Also, I would suggest to give few seconds sleep before selecting the option.