# Xpath or Css selector for this element - HELPP

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I have spent like 5 hours trying to find the selector for that success message down there , for my Selenium c# test with not luck. My test always fail saying cannot locate the element!!

**Any idea what selector I can use???**

I have tried xpath, Css, Classname with all the plugins...

```html
public IWebElement alertSuccessfulAlert => WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Registration is successful')]"));

public IWebElement alertSuccessfulAlert => WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body:nth-child(2) my-app:nth-child(1) div.container:nth-child(2) > main.row:nth-child(1)"));
```

[image][image]

Comment: Your XPath is looking correct. What error do you see? Maybe you just missing some delay before accessing that element?

Comment: Use this generic xpath:
Message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(.,"Register")]//following::div[contains(@class,"alert")]')

Comment: Is it possible to share page URL ?

Comment: this is the page https://buggy.justtestit.org/register

Comment: The error I get is that the element is not found, it doesn't find that selector via Xpath, CSS and so on

Answer (score 0):

The bubble message <kbd>Registration is successful</kbd> is generated through a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) so you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath`:

  ```
    public IWebElement alertSuccessfulAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Registration is successful')]")));
  ```