# Selenium: How to use findElement(By.cssSelector) to extract text from HTML

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Hello I want you to get the text **@user** i.e. `( span class="user" )`  from Class messenger using `driver.FindElementsByCssSelector('');`

Because the same code is on the same page, but with a different start div class="messenger"

Note: The code cannot be changed on the site

```
<div class="messenger">
    <div class="two"> 
        <div class="three">  
            <a class="complex" rel="user" href="https://example.com"> 
                <img class="avatar pull-right" src="https://example.co/a.jpg" alt="avatar"> 
            </a>    
        </div> 
        <div class="webs">      
            <a class="link-complex" rel="user" href="afaq"> 
                <b class="link-complex-target">website</b> 
                <span class="user">@user</span> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text *`@user`* so you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *ClassName*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("user"))).Text);
  ```
- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span.user"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[@class='user']"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```