# How to click on the radio button with label Yes using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

HTML Snapshot:

[image]

Element Snapshot:

[image]

I want to write xpath for 'Yes' label (Green color mentioned in UI image). I'm new for automation & Please help me to resolve. I have add my HTML code & UI

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of code or data](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post a text here so people are able to use it to very their answer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) is basically an *`<input>`* element associated with the *`<label>`* with text as *Yes* and to [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on it you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(., 'Yes')]//ancestor::input[1]")).Click();
  ```

---

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [ElementToBeClickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//label[contains(., 'Yes')]//ancestor::input[1]"))).Click();
  ```