# Selenium-C#: How to click on a button when it is clickable and not having the disabled attribute in Blazor Web Application

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a 'save' button which is only clickable when 4 text fields before are filled with text.

In the inspect there are 2 buttons. The Cancel (Abbrechen) button is always clickable, but the save (Speichern) button has an "disabled" parameter in HTML which makes the button not clickable. As soon as the button is clickable, the "Disabled" Parameter disappears.

```html
<div class="mud-dialog-actions">
  <!--!-->
  <!--!-->
  <button type="button" class="mud-button-root mud-button mud-button-text mud-button-text-default mud-button-text-size-medium mud-ripple button"      _bl_65608b69-0cf8-4c0e-a2ad-634125333afc=""><span class="mud-button-label">Abbrechen</span></button>
  <!--!-->
  <!--!-->
  <button type="submit" class="mud-button-root mud-button mud-button-text mud-button-text-success mud-button-text-size-medium mud-ripple button button--blue" _bl_8df46032-6965-4980-8c8c-6d3881a66eea="" disabled="">
    <span class="mud-button-label">Speichern</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I tried to use this selenium method:

```
var element = _webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(buttonSelector)));
element.Click();
```

But this method doesnt help me as it jumps to `element.Click()` even when button is not clickable and then it throws an exception.

Is there any other way, to check if a button is clickable?

---

### Update

I also tried:

```
bool elementEnabled = element.Enabled
```

It returns always true even when the button is not clickable

Comment: Instead of the image update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I added the HTML code snippet above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke click on the element with text ***Speichern*** when the ***`disabled`*** attribute is no more present inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.mud-dialog-actions button[type='submit']:not(disabled)"))).Click();
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='mud-dialog-actions']//button[@type='submit' and not(@disabled)]"))).Click();
  ```