# How to click on an list element within ol using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am working with C# selenium as an amateur. How can I select the country on the site below. I tried many things but I couldn't choose.

Url: " https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_counternotice?product=websearch "

Snapshot of the element:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the `<li>` element with text ***Afghanistan*** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.sc-select[aria-label^='Country of residence']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("ol.sc-select-show li[id=':2']"))).Click();
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='sc-select' and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Country of residence')]"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//ol[@class='sc-select-show']//li[text()='Afghanistan']"))).Click();
  ```