# How to click on <li> element within <ul> listbox using Python3 and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, listbox, html-lists

I have an issue with navigating in the listbox made of UL list using Selenium 4.3 and Python 3. The problem is that I don't know how to switch value from default to any other and when I'm trying to use click method on those `<li>` elements I'm getting only errors.

The screen shot of the html code below:

[image]

First I was trying to open whole list by clicking on it and after that choosing the element by the second click. I was trying to access that by ID, like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "__list1").click()
```

But it was an error that the asked element doesn't exist.

Do you have any idea how to navigate to different element from this kind of dropdown list? I know how to deal with this problem if the HTML tag would be a `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

[image: snapshot]

The element identified through `(By.ID, "__list1")` is a [`<ul>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) tag which are generally **not** clickable.

---

### Solution

Just like the usecase within the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091870/how-to-click-on-an-list-element-within-ol-using-selenium-and-c-sharp) you need to locate a `<div>` or a `<span>` element, which being clicked expands the `<li>` elements within either a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Your effective code block will be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "div_or_span_which_expands_li"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sapUiSimpleFixFlexContent']/ul//li[text()='All Cases']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: As you adviced I change the click() on the element that expands the ul list and this works great. The element looks like <span> with id "__pane1-defaultSetDDLB-label". But in case of your solution - i still can not click the element of the list. I don't know if the xpath should be longer (for example should it start with the body tag and goes to the <li> element)?  This line does an error with tiemout with backtrace:
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::unpack [0x00007FF7B7F16312+24642