# Unable to locate WebElement using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I've been knocking my head trying to figure out why I can't locate and click this web element!

What I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward, I'm trying to click on any item of the following list: [worten list of airpods](https://www.worten.pt/search?query=airpods)
And I'm basically trying to locate AND click in some element of this kind:
[image]

It's completely impossible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already tried every type of xpath that I could remember, the only thing that comes close to working is when I copy the full xpath directly from the browser, but even then another error appears stating that the element isn't clickable...and obviously I don't want to deal with a full xpath.

examples of xpaths tried:

- //a[@data-sku='7328250'] and its variations (@href instead of @data-sku, etc...)
- same thing but with css selectors.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9lox.png) provided to click on the desired element you can use the *`aria-label`* attribute of the `<a>` element and inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[aria-label^='APPLE Airpods Pro 2ª Geração']")));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[starts-with(@aria-label, 'APPLE Airpods Pro 2ª Geração')]")));
  ```

Comment: Hey, I'll try this, haven't tried this approach.

Comment: This does seem to work (doesn't return an error)  but it doesn't go to the next page.

Comment: While trying with Python clients I am getting detected as a bot and unable to access the url. So the most probhable reason, your program is being detected as a bot and the navigation is halted.

Comment: Ok so it's the website's fault. So I guess there's no workaround?

Comment: Honestly there are but that's all together a huge discussion and would be out of scope for this question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040904/7429447) discussion.