# Selenium C#: Can't find a button on Trello

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate the Trello Activity extension, and I am trying to automatically press the button "Export to CSV" with Selenium.

And my code, I am trying to get the button with xPath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\'content\']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/div/button")).Click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("/html/body/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]/button")));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > section > div:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > button")).Click();`
```

Here is the button:

[image]

And this is its html:

[image]

I am trying to automate Trello Activity extension, and I am trying to automatically press the button "Export to CSV" with Selenium.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as [*Export to CSV*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc16I.png) is with an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451578/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframeCssSelector]"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("body > section > div:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > button"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("iframeXPath"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//html/body/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]/button"))).Click();
  ```