# How to stay current on a popup window?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

So I clicked on a sign in button with selenium c# and it open up a pop up window saying choose account. I want to click on the option  use another account but it wont work.

i tried using driver.FindElement(By.Id("otherTile")).Click(); but it wont work. i also triewd using the window handler but it didnt work.   here is the html code .

```
                   <div id="otherTile" class="table" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-labelledby="otherTileText" data-bind="
                css: { 'list-item': svr.fSupportWindowsStyles },
                click: otherTile_onClick,
                pressEnter: otherTile_onClick">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell tile-img">
                        <img class="tile-img" role="presentation" pngsrc="https://aadcdn.msauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_c9929da7ed2c1ed4745e4035cf5441cd.png" svgsrc="https://aadcdn.msauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_56e73414003cdb676008ff7857343074.svg" data-bind="imgSrc" src="https://aadcdn.msauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_56e73414003cdb676008ff7857343074.svg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="table-cell text-left content" data-bind="css: { 'content': !svr.fSupportWindowsStyles }">
                        <div id="otherTileText" data-bind="text: otherTileText">Use another account</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is it by any chance in an iframe? If so, you need to switch to it.

Comment: noo there is no iframe

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be a dynamic element within a popup you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451578/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.table#otherTile[aria-labelledby='otherTileText']"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='table' and @id='otherTile'][@[aria-labelledby='otherTileText']"))).Click();
  ```

---

### Update

Incase you are using `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` with `nuget`:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='table' and @id='otherTile'][@[aria-labelledby='otherTileText']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Expected conditions doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ghosty What error do you see?

Comment: Expected condition doesn't not exist in the current context.

Comment: @ghosty in order to test it, try putting there time.sleep(2) to see if you need to for that element

Comment: @ghosty Checkout the answer update. Do check the embedded links for further references.